# How to Localize "CHOOSE AN ITEM" text on PickerFlyoutBase of ComboBox in WP8.1

Tags: xaml, combobox, localization, windows-phone-8.1

How do I localize the PickerFlyoutBase.Title of a ComboBox in the Resources.resw language resource file in WP 8.1?

```
<ComboBox x:Uid="myUid" PlaceholderText="Some Text" PickerFlyoutBase.Title="Changed Text">
  <ComboBoxItem Content="a"/>
</ComboBox>
```

PickerFlyoutBase.Title is the text to replace the CHOOSE AN ITEM text on the flyout.

Answer (score 2):

I had real trouble with this and finally with some support which led me in the right direction I managed to get the syntax correct, this is entered in the Name column of the Resources.resw file.

```
myUid.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives]PickerFlyoutBase.Title
```